# How to prevent skinning in a particular adf table among many tables

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have two adf tables and applied skinning for the table.Now it is displaying skinning for the two tables.My requirement is to get skinning for single table only.How to apply skinning for one table among many tables in adf application.

//my css file
This code i'm using for getting alternative background color for the adf rows.I want it for only one table.

```
    af|table::data-row af|column::data-cell{
    background-color:rgb(234,255,252);
    }

    af|table::data-row af|column::banded-data-cell{
    background-color:White;
    }
    af|column::column-header-cell
    {
      color: Black;

      font-weight: bold;
    }
   // trinidad-skins.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
    <skins xmlns="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/skin">
      <skin>
        <id>skin.desktop</id>
        <family>skin</family>
        <extends>fusionFx-v1.desktop</extends>
        <render-kit-id>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.desktop</render-kit-id>
        <style-sheet-name>skins/tablerowcolor.css</style-sheet-name>
      </skin>
    </skins>
   // trinidad-config.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
    <trinidad-config xmlns="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/config">

      <!--<skin-family>skyros</skin-family>
      <skin-version>v1</skin-version>-->
      <skin-family>skin</skin-family>

    </trinidad-config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS Classes to style the special table, and leave out the default without styling

For instance change the code to the following:

```
af|table.stylesTable::data-row af|column::data-cell{
background-color:rgb(234,255,252);
}

af|table.stylesTable::data-row af|column::banded-data-cell{
background-color:White;
}
af|column.stylesTable::column-header-cell
{
  color: Black;

  font-weight: bold;
}
```

And in your JSPX or JSF change the styleClass of the table to **stylesTable** and don't input anything in the one that you don't want to style.

Comment: it is working fine but i'm having styleClass="AFStretchWidth" and when i replace it with styleClass="stylesTable" then width is not stretching.i need width also.will u help on this.